# How do I make my add to cart button sticky on Shopify?

Tags: button, shopify

How to create a sticky 'Add to cart' button for Shopify?

I'm using the app but it's increase my website loading time.

So I'm looking for the custom code for sticky add to cart button

Answer (score 0):

This answer will work for Dawn based themes.
In main-product.liquid add a new section setting

```
    {
      "type": "checkbox",
      "id": "show_sticky_cart_button",
      "label": "Show sticky add to cart button to the bottom of the page",
      "default": true
    },
```

Add this code just above product-modal tag

```
  {%- if section.settings.show_sticky_cart_button-%}
    {% render 'product-sticky-form', product: product %}
  {%- endif -%}
```

Create the snippet product-sticky-form.liquid and add the following

```
{{ 'product-sticky-form.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

<script src="{{ 'product-sticky-form.js' | asset_url }}" defer="defer"></script>

{%- assign sticky_product_form_id = 'product-form-' | append: section.id -%}

<sticky-product-form class="product--sticky-form product--sticky-form__inactive">
  <product-form>
  {%- form 'product', product, id: sticky_product_form_id, class: 'form', novalidate: 'novalidate', data-type: 'add-to-cart-form' -%}

  <div class="product--sticky-form-info">
    <input
        type="hidden"
        name="id"
        value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}"
        disabled
      >
    <span class="h2">{{ product.title | escape }}</span>
    <div class="no-js-hidden" id="price-{{ section.id }}" role="status" {{ block.shopify_attributes }}>
        {%- render 'price', product: product, use_variant: true, show_badges: true, price_class: 'price--end' -%}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product--sticky-form__quantity product-form__quantity{% if settings.inputs_shadow_vertical_offset != 0 and settings.inputs_shadow_vertical_offset < 0 %} product-form__quantity-top{% endif %}">
    <quantity-input class="quantity">
        <button class="quantity__button no-js-hidden" name="minus" type="button">
        <span class="visually-hidden">
            {{- 'products.product.quantity.decrease' | t: product: product.title | escape -}}
        </span>
        {% render 'icon-minus' %}
        </button>
        <input
        class="quantity__input"
        type="number"
        name="quantity"
        id="Quantity-{{ section.id }}"
        min="1"
        value="1"
        >
        <button class="quantity__button no-js-hidden" name="plus" type="button">
        <span class="visually-hidden">
            {{- 'products.product.quantity.increase' | t: product: product.title | escape -}}
        </span>
        {% render 'icon-plus' %}
        </button>
    </quantity-input>
  </div>
  {%- unless product.has_only_default_variant -%}
  <div class="product--sticky-form__variants">
    <variant-selects
            class="no-js-hidden"
            data-section="{{ section.id }}"
            data-url="{{ product.url }}"
            {{ block.shopify_attributes }}
            >
            {%- for option in product.options_with_values -%}
              <div class="product-form__input product-form__input--dropdown">
                <div class="select">
                    <select
                    id="Option-{{ section.id }}-{{ forloop.index0 }}"
                    class="select__select"
                    name="options[{{ option.name | escape }}]"
                    form="{{ sticky_product_form_id }}"
                    >
                    {%- for value in option.values -%}
                        <option
                        value="{{ value | escape }}"
                        {% if option.selected_value == value %}
                            selected="selected"
                        {% endif %}
                        >
                        {{ value }}
                        </option>
                    {%- endfor -%}
                    </select>
                    {% render 'icon-caret' %}
                </div>
              </div>
            {%- endfor -%}

            <script type="application/json">
                {{ product.variants | json }}
            </script>
    </variant-selects>
    <noscript class="product-form__noscript-wrapper-{{ section.id }}">
      <div class="product-form__input{% if product.has_only_default_variant %} hidden{% endif %}">
        <div class="select">
          <select
              name="id"
              id="Variants-{{ section.id }}"
              class="select__select"
              form="{{ sticky_product_form_id }}"
          >
              {%- for variant in product.variants -%}
              <option
                  {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %}
                  selected="selected"
                  {% endif %}
                  {% if variant.available == false %}
                  disabled
                  {% endif %}
                  value="{{ variant.id }}"
              >
                  {{ variant.title }}
                  {%- if variant.available == false %} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}{% endif %}
                  - {{ variant.price | money | strip_html }}
              </option>
              {%- endfor -%}
          </select>
          {% render 'icon-caret' %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </noscript>
    </div>    
    {% endunless %}
    <div class="product--sticky-form__buttons">
        <div class="product-form__error-message-wrapper" role="alert" hidden>
          <svg
            aria-hidden="true"
            focusable="false"
            role="presentation"
            class="icon icon-error"
            viewBox="0 0 13 13"
          >
            <circle cx="6.5" cy="6.50049" r="5.5" stroke="white" stroke-width="2"/>
            <circle cx="6.5" cy="6.5" r="5.5" fill="#EB001B" stroke="#EB001B" stroke-width="0.7"/>
            <path d="M5.87413 3.52832L5.97439 7.57216H7.02713L7.12739 3.52832H5.87413ZM6.50076 9.66091C6.88091 9.66091 7.18169 9.37267 7.18169 9.00504C7.18169 8.63742 6.88091 8.34917 6.50076 8.34917C6.12061 8.34917 5.81982 8.63742 5.81982 9.00504C5.81982 9.37267 6.12061 9.66091 6.50076 9.66091Z" fill="white"/>
            <path d="M5.87413 3.17832H5.51535L5.52424 3.537L5.6245 7.58083L5.63296 7.92216H5.97439H7.02713H7.36856L7.37702 7.58083L7.47728 3.537L7.48617 3.17832H7.12739H5.87413ZM6.50076 10.0109C7.06121 10.0109 7.5317 9.57872 7.5317 9.00504C7.5317 8.43137 7.06121 7.99918 6.50076 7.99918C5.94031 7.99918 5.46982 8.43137 5.46982 9.00504C5.46982 9.57872 5.94031 10.0109 6.50076 10.0109Z" fill="white" stroke="#EB001B" stroke-width="0.7">
          </svg>
          <span class="product-form__error-message"></span>
        </div>  
        <input
          type="hidden"
          name="id"
          value="{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.id }}"
          disabled
        >
        <div class="product-form__buttons">
          <button
            type="submit"
            name="add"
            class="product-form__submit button button--full-width button--primary"
            {% if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.available == false %}
              disabled
            {% endif %}
          >
            <span>
              {%- if product.selected_or_first_available_variant.available -%}
                {{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}
              {%- else -%}
                {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
              {%- endif -%}
            </span>
            <div class="loading-overlay__spinner hidden">
              <svg
                aria-hidden="true"
                focusable="false"
                role="presentation"
                class="spinner"
                viewBox="0 0 66 66"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              >
                <circle class="path" fill="none" stroke-width="6" cx="33" cy="33" r="30"></circle>
              </svg>
            </div>
          </button>
        </div>  
      
    </div>
    {%- endform -%}
  </product-form>
</sticky-product-form>
```

Create the asset product-sticky-form.js and add the following

```
customElements.define('sticky-product-form', class StickyProductForm extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      this.productForm = document.querySelector('product-form');

      this.productStickyForm = document.querySelector('.product--sticky-form');
      this.productFormBounds = {};

      this.onScrollHandler = this.onScroll.bind(this);
      window.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollHandler, false);

      this.createObserver();
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.onScrollHandler);
    }

    createObserver() {
      let observer = new IntersectionObserver((entries, observer) => {
        this.productFormBounds = entries[0].isIntersecting;
      });
      observer.observe(this.productForm);
    }

    onScroll() {
      this.productFormBounds ? requestAnimationFrame(this.hide.bind(this)) : requestAnimationFrame(this.reveal.bind(this));
    }

    hide() {
      if(this.productStickyForm.classList.contains('product--sticky-form__active')) {
        this.productStickyForm.classList.remove('product--sticky-form__active');
        this.productStickyForm.classList.add('product--sticky-form__inactive');
      }
    }

    reveal() {
      if(this.productStickyForm.classList.contains('product--sticky-form__inactive')) {
        this.productStickyForm.classList.add('product--sticky-form__active');
        this.productStickyForm.classList.remove('product--sticky-form__inactive');
      }
    }
  });
```

Create the asset product-sticky-form.css and add the following

```
.product--sticky-form {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color:rgba(243,243,243,0.5);
}

.product--sticky-form__inactive {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 1.15s ease-out, opacity 1.15s ease-out;
}

.product--sticky-form__active {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1.15s ease-out;
}

.product--sticky-form form{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.product--sticky-form-info {
  font-size: clamp(0.75rem, 2vw, calc(var(--font-heading-scale) * 4rem));
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.product--sticky-form .price {
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.product--sticky-form__buttons {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 438px;
  height: 47px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.product--sticky-form__variants,
.product--sticky-form__quantity {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 990px) {
  .product--sticky-form__variants,
  .product--sticky-form__quantity {
    height: 47px;
    display: block;
  }
}



.quick-add-modal .product--sticky-form {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I made a small change so your code will work :)

Comment: This definitely worked for version 7 but there has been many updates since then. Please share your updated code for the next person.

Comment: I've submitting an edit, please review it.